# Channels - Share link not shown in mobile view

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, stack-overflow-for-teams, sharing

The 'share' link below a post isn't visible in the mobile view, while it's available in the desktop mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! As of a few minutes ago share shows up below Channels questions and answers on the mobile view, thanks for spotting this.